# Should I use JobExecution.beforeJob() or a Tasklet?

Tags: spring-batch

My Spring Batch application first extracts a zip file into a individual files before sending them to be processed by steps.

What are the pro & cons of using a JobExecutionListener.beforeJob() over a Tasklet  for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Listener in below cases

1. Supporting functionalities not main tasks such as

   - Logging
   - Reporting

I ask the question to myself, what if I remove the listener, does it cause any problem for the job or not. If 'No' as the answer, it means the design for listener is correct.

2. Work outside transaction. Below are Listener/Methods are outside transaction

   - beforeJob
   - afterJob
   - beforeStep
   - afterStep
   - afterChunk
3. Work inside transaction. Below are Listener/Methods are inside transaction

   - beforeChunk
   - beforeRead/afterRead/onReadError
   - beforeProcess/afterProcess/onProcessError
   - beforeWrite/afterWrite/onWriteError
   - onSkipInRead/onSkipInWrite/onSkipInProcess
4. Which we want to NOT rollback when exceptions happens by marking exceptions as Not-Rollback-Exception
5. Initialize some caches or profile data which will be re-used across your job

Comment: thanks @Nghia Do for the guidelines. Can the listeners (job or step) be used for initialization purpose, such as unzipping received files, or parsing metadata ?

Comment: In your case, I would like to go with Tasklet because it is part of the flow of your job. The failure of that tasklet may stop the subsequence steps.